# Webpack Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined after removing node_modules from bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs

```
bundle.js      2.83 kB   0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  3.36 kB   0  [emitted]  main
```

When I add the code below with the custom externals, I can remove the `node_modules` from being directly included in the `bundle.js` output.

```
bundle.js      743 kB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  864 kB       0  [emitted]  main
```

This significantly reduces the bundle size. **But I get an error in the browser saying:** `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in the browser. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
var path = require("path"),
  fs = require("fs");

// return what's in the node modules folder apart from ".bin"
const nodeModules = fs
  .readdirSync("./node_modules")
  .filter(d => d != ".bin");

/**
 * Remove non-direct references to modules from bundles
 *
 * @param {any} context
 * @param {any} request
 * @param {any} callback
 * @returns
 */
function ignoreNodeModules(context, request, callback) {
  // IF someone is importing a module e.g. "import {chatModule} from
  // "./components/chat" using a relative path, then we're okay with them bringing
  // in into the bundle
  if (request[0] == ".") 
    return callback();

  // IF someone is doing "import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject" only want to know
  // if first part is a node_module
  const module = request.split("/")[0];
  if (nodeModules.indexOf(module) !== -1) {
    // append "commonjs " - tells webpack to go and grab from node_modules instead
    // of including in bundle
    return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
  }

  return callback();
}

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  // Runs our custom function everytime webpack sees a module
  externals: [ignoreNodeModules]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your bundle is smaller because you're not including your `node_modules`, but this leads to a fundamental problem: **you no longer send your dependencies to the browser, so your code can't run at all**. As you probably know, browsers don't natively support `require()`, so your current `ignoreNodeModules` function tells Webpack to skip bundling them and leave in the `require()`, but the browser doesn't know how to handle it.

If you want to reduce bundle size, consider using Webpack's [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) so that you only bundle dependencies that are needed for each page/section. Alternatively, you could consider using a browser-side `require()` loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Using `externals` is only really useful for distributing server-side Node libraries, where you would expect consumers of your library to provide your dependencies rather than bundling them with your library.

The comments on the [documentation about `externals`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) are also worth reading for some further context on the issue.

Comment: When it comes to best practice, would it be better to do code-splitting or using a browser-side require() loader such as RequireJS?

Comment: It depends on your server and app. If you're using HTTP2, the answer is *don't bundle at all*, because it can handle multiple concurrent requests easily. Otherwise, I would use code splitting because Webpack supports it a bit better than RequireJS (but there's nothing *technically* wrong with it).

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot for that advice. I haven't heard a lot about HTTP2 before, but I'll look into it :) otherwise I'll go with code-splitting and see how it goes.

Comment: @ClementOh glad it helped - don't forget to accept if you consider this question solved now. If you have any further questions related to this, feel free to reply here with the link so I get a notification and I'll try to take a look!

Comment: Done. Thanks for the offer! Really appreciate your help! I actually do have a question on webpack and express in the link below. Would be great to see what you think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959835/webpack-express-cannot-resolve-module-fs-request-dependency-is-expression