# Webpack Express Cannot Resolve Module 'fs', Request Dependency is Expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When I include Express in my project I always get these errors when I try to build with webpack.

webpack.config.dev.js

```
var path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "server": "./server/server.ts"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/public/"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      }, {
        test: /\.js(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"]
      }, {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried:

1. Installing 'fs' but it doesn't work
2. Read somewhere to change the node fs property. It removes the error warnings but I don't think this is a good permanent solution.

   ```
   module.exports = {
     node: {
       fs: "empty"
     }
   }
   ```

   Time: 2496ms
               Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
           bundle.js  761 kB       0  [emitted]  server
       bundle.js.map  956 kB       0  [emitted]  server
           + 119 hidden modules

   WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js
   Critical dependencies:
   78:29-56 the request of a dependency is an expression
    @ ./~/express/lib/view.js 78:29-56
   ERROR in ./~/express/lib/view.js

   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/clementoh/Desktop/boilerplate2/node_modules/express/lib
    @ ./~/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22
   ERROR in ./~/send/index.js

   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/clementoh/Desktop/boilerplate2/node_modules/send
        @ ./~/send/index.js 24:9-22
       ERROR in ./~/etag/index.js

   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/clementoh/Desktop/boilerplate2/node_modules/etag
    @ ./~/etag/index.js 22:12-25
   ERROR in ./~/destroy/index.js

   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/clementoh/Desktop/boilerplate2/node_modules/destroy
    @ ./~/destroy/index.js 14:17-30
   ERROR in ./~/mime/mime.js

   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/clementoh/Desktop/boilerplate2/node_modules/mime
    @ ./~/mime/mime.js 2:9-22

Comment: Have you tried adding `"target": "node"` to your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Oh haha that actually fixed the 'fs' problem :) How would I go about resolving the warning? - `Critical dependencies: 78:29-56 the request of a dependency is an expression @ ./~/express/lib/view.js 78:29-56 ERROR in ./~/express/lib/view.js`

Comment: I recall being able to get rid of this kind of a thing multiple times already by simply destroying the `node_modules` folder and doing `npm install` again.

Comment: Also, do you actually need Webpack at all here @ClementOh? Is there a need for you to bundle everything or could you just run it through Babel instead?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to create my own redux server-side-rendering boilerplate so I'll need to bundle things like SASS, compile tsx etc. Unfortunately deleting `node_modules` didn't work for me, I'm trying to google it at the moment, didn't find much but will post it when I find something.

Comment: @ClementOh the issue is your `./~/express/lib/view.js` contains a `require` that is based on a variable, and Webpack doesn't know how to resolve the path at compile time. Is there any way you could avoid doing that?

Comment: @Aurora0001 I don't think that's possible. I can't physically edit the express library and the error occurs every time I initialise Express.

Comment: @Aurora0001 just thought I should add that the server still runs fine even with the warning. The callback `const app = Express(); app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server running"));` runs as expected.

Comment: Below `module: {`, try adding `"noParse": /\.\/~\/express\/lib\/view\.js/` and see if that removes the warning.

Comment: Unfortunately adding `noParse: /\.\/~\/express\/lib\/view\.js/` it doesn't seem to remove the warning.

Comment: @ClementOh I *think* you can suppress the warning by adding `exprContextCritical: false,` under `module`. Test it and see, but I suspect it's better not to suppress it if you can avoid doing it.

Comment: @Aurora0001 `exprContextCritical: false` definitely does its job, but I agree with you that it's better not to suppress it. Perhaps its something for the express github issues page

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3420)

Comment: Did you ever fully resolve this issue?
I added both target: 'node' and node: {fs: 'empty'}, but am still getting these stupid fs errors. Not sure what else to do...

Comment: `target: 'node'` should only be added if you are using webpack to build your server-side code. If you're using a static react SPA, you should never use `target: 'node'` because it doesn't bundle your dependencies and your app may fail to load properly. I think I ended up including `node_modules` in the bundle and using react-router to split the code and lower the initial SPA load time.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just posting an answer, since not everyone reads comments on SO. @Aurora0001 nailed it. Webpack's config needs to have this set:

```
"target": "node"
```

Comment: If I am building a web application, is it right to set target as 'node'?

Comment: @AbhishekNalin no, it is not. You should set `target: web`

Comment: where in webpack.config should I add this?

Comment: See this: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/ You add it to the root-level configuration object.

Comment: this will create another issue

Comment: Actually, I first thought this was a solution, but then like @SarathAk said, it created another problem for me. I think this may be the solution: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447#issuecomment-285598881

Answer (score 4):

I am on a stack Angular 2 - Electron - Webpack and I needed to use fs into my service, I finally found how to do :

1) inside your webpack.common.js, specify `target:'electron-renderer'`

2) inside your service or component : `import * as fs from 'fs';` and use fs as would do for a node project.

Hope it help !

Comment: adding `import * as fs from 'fs'` in my node app saddly was also not a solution :/

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by two steps:

1. Delete `node_modules` directory
2. Add `target:'node'` into webpack config file

Then run `npm install`. It worked for me fine.

Answer (score 2):

I added `node: { fs: 'empty' }` without luck,

then I added --config to start command:

`webpack-dev-sever webpack.config.dev.js`

Use --config flag to use the custom file.

`webpack-dev-sever --config webpack.config.dev.js`

Answer (score 1):

#### Working Solution/Hack/Patch for Angular V6 and up

The solution for me was to hack the Angular-CLI module to spoof the missing node modules.

After installing locate the following file:

```
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js
```

Find the `node` line and add this:

```
node: { crypto: true, stream: true, fs: 'empty', net: 'empty' }
```

And that's it!!!

Note: You will need to do this patch every time you update the package. So use this script:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "node patch-webpack.js"
  ...
}
```

**patch-webpack.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const f = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  let result = data.replace(/node: false/g, "node: {crypto: true, stream: true, fs: 'empty', net: 'empty'}");

  fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Source:
https://blog.lysender.com/2018/07/angular-6-cannot-resolve-crypto-fs-net-path-stream-when-building-angular/

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"target": "node",` works by adding it to the `webpack.config.js`.